# Viber already active on PC; want to activate the same Viber account on Android without SIM card

Tags: sim-card, viber-messenger

I already have Viber installed on my PC and want to install it on my Android now. Want to use the same old mobile number with Viber but I cannot receive SMS on that old number.

I don't know how to receive a Viber activation code on my PC Viber, for example.

How to activate Viber on Android without a SIM card?

Comment: `but I cannot receive SMS on that old number` Why?

Comment: for example, its a pay as you go SIM or, sim from different country and now i live in a diff country and forgot to deactivate the older number -- all contacts have your previous number... many examples..

Comment: I believe there is no way around it. You can ask their support to make an exception for your situation. I don't think you got an other choice.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on the [Viber Support Docs](https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/1340166-viber-setup-for-android#.VNIPpNKnVC0)

> You will receive an SMS message with your Viber access code

You will require to receive an SMS (or use the [automatic callback feature](https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/articles/1379211-how-do-i-use-automatic-callback-#.VNIQWdKnVC1)) to be able to activate. You will have to necessarily use either of the above options to activate Viber on your phone.

Comment: Thanks but everybody knows this. Question is if there is any other way or not.

Comment: There is no way IMO. Hence I posted this